# Migration doesn't automatically create schema?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, migration

Is anybody have problems with creating database in Laravel 4.1? Previous version was normal, but in 4.1 i create new database with

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --create --table=users
```

and laravel don't put timestamps and increments automatically in migration.

Comment: Same issue.  If you go into the Users model and put `public $timestamps = true;` that may auto add the timestamps

Comment: Well, it didn't create anything for me, and i find out that i was writing wrong syntax. The right way is to write

--create=tablename 

and that worked for me

Comment: So the better way to create tables is using Way/Generator tools.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax for creating a migration file has slightly changed in Laravel 4.1.

**Laravel 4.1**

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --create=users
```

**Laravel 4.0**

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --table=users --create
```

See the [Creating Migrations](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#creating-migrations) section in the Laravel documentation and make sure to select **4.1** in the top.

Comment: I just created a Laravel 4.1 project, and I used the command you show as 4.0 sytnax (ie. --table=users --create) and it worked just fine.